# Run a program with python with additional parameters

Tags: python, tshark

I am trying to run `tshark.exe` with the parameters `-i ethernet -f udp`, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that in Python. Here is a part of the code

```
from geolite2 import geolite2
import socket, subprocess

cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe"

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
my_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
reader = geolite2.reader()
```

Running the same thing, but as `cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe -i ethernet -f udp` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), arguments can be specified in a list. So in your case,

```
cmd = [r"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe", '-i', 'ethernet', '-f', 'udp']
```

should work.

Comment: Hmm... that didn't give me an syntax error which is a step in the right direction, but I still get no output. I used this ```cmd = [r"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe", '-i ethernet', '-f udp']``` but the output still doesn't work. The output should display the ip's of any connections using udp and its geolocation

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass arguments from command line to a python script, then you can use the sys module with argv, like so:

```
import sys
program_name = sys.argv[0]
arguments = sys.argv[1:]
count = len(arguments)
```

While with the command line you just separate the arguments with space. An example:

```
python ex.py hello world
```

Where each argument would return:

```
print(sys.argv[0])
```

> ex.py

```
print(sys.argv[1])
```

> hello

```
print(sys.argv[2])
```

> world

More info can be found [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/argv/more-fun-with-sys-argv).